# How can I prevent a TextView from changing its size when inserting a String? (Android)

Tags: android, textview, autosize, text-size

I've built a square Tic Tac Toe field in my android app 
which fills the whole screen width.

But everytime I **insert a string** into a cell via setText method it changes the size of this cell (dependent on the size of the inserted String).

How can I insert a (maximum-sized) String/char into a cell **without changing its size**?

The code is pretty long but I can upload it if necessary.

[image: after inserting a String]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define in `xml`:

`android:maxWidth="200dp"`

or java:

```
textView.setMaxWidth(300);
```

Also you can give the `TextView` a percentage of the screen using `LinearLayout`, for example if we have a table of 3 columns, we do:

```
<LinearLayout android:width="match_parent"
              android:height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="3">

              <TextView android:width="0dp"
                        android:height="wrap_content"
                        android:weight="1"/>

              <TextView android:width="0dp"
                        android:height="wrap_content"
                        android:weight="1"/>

              <TextView android:width="0dp"
                        android:height="wrap_content"
                        android:weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

By doing that, every `TextView` will get 1 out of 3 of the width of its parent which has a `match_parent` width.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the exact width and height it has (and shall keep) because it depends on the screen-width of the device...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the other answer, I assume you mean the TextView is expanding in height. (multi-line)

To fix this, use the following in your xml:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

This will limit your TextView to a single line, and if it extends past it, it will display a "..." at the end.